# Anchor tag not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

The first thing is that the code is written in HTML and now I am changing this code in Wordpress. I have a home page where I have created a top menu which has links to several other pages.

This is the code I used to link it:

```
<a href="facilities.php">facilities</a>
```

This was working fine when I was doing in in HTML, but it's not working when I am opening my page in localhost. When I click it, it shows a message that no content is found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add base url at first. For wordpress, you can do this with `get_template_directory_uri().'/facilities.php'`
Here, i assumed 'facilities.php' is located on your base directory if there is more directory you need to add those too. Hope, it helps.

Comment: Could you provide me the folder structure of your project?